# Side loading an Outlook javascript add-in

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, office-addins

I am having a horrible time getting started at creating an add-in for Outlook. I want to use the new html/javascript/manifest approach. I have been able to create a manifest and application which works great with outlook.live.com. Where I am completely getting stuck is with desktop Outlook. How do I install/debug my add-in with desktop Outlook?

I cannot find anything in the UI which will let me add this style of add-in. Additionally the [Microsoft documentation](http://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/outlook/testing-and-tips) did not make things any clearer. Their docs seem to hint using this type of add-in is only possible if you are connecting to an Exchange server.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the add-in will load on Outlook desktop only if your mailbox is Exchange. I am not sure the add-ins work with a personal Microsoft account (e.g hotmail.com, outlook.com) and Office desktop. Keep in mind that the support of mail add-ins for personal account is relatively new (officially announced in march 2016).

To develop your add-in I suggest you to use a organizational account (i.e. Office365 account). Support for organizational account has been released in 2013 and is a much more mature solution for you to get started. You can have a free dev account at dev.office.com.

**Edit: October 2016** personal account are supported now by "Personal mailbox accounts" aka outlook.com accounts

Let us keep in mind that a mail add-in is not installed on a mail client (desktop, OWA) but on the mail account. When you "install" an add-in you only set a xml file on your mailbox that basically says "there is a web add-in out there called X and that is served at this url...". Then, if you install add-in X on your mailbox smaclell@mytestcompany.onmicrosoft.com, this add-in will load the add-in web iframes whether you are consulting your mailbox with Outlook Web Access (OWA) or Outlook Desktop.

To install the add-in for one user mailaccount, you have to use the Outlook Web Access. See this [blog post](http://simonjaeger.com/installing-add-ins-in-outlook-2016-and-outlook-online/). Note also that you can install the add-in for the whole organisation (Admin > Exchange Admin > Add-ins). Finally, Visual Studio is also able to push the manifest to your office 365 mailbox. To have this you need [Office Development Tools](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/office-tools-vs.aspx).

For debugging in Outlook Desktop, I know two approaches.

1. Use the Office Developement Tools with visual studio
   and select your sample add-in project as 'Starting project' and in properties select 'Office Desktop'.
   [image: Office Dev Tools]
2. Plain web development.
   Personally, I do not use really much the Office Development Tools. I install manually my add-in with "https://localhost:XXXX" for url and I start the web project on IIS express to do the debugging. For stepping into the source code, I use the debugger of my browser (Chrome, Edge, IE etc.) when browsing in OWA. When I need to step into source code specifically on Desktop (For windows or for Mac) I use [Vorlon.js](http://vorlonjs.com/) see also this [blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mim/2016/02/18/vorlonjs-plugin-for-debugging-office-addin/).
   My advice is also to test/debug frequently with IE 11 (still available in Win10!) and OWA. Indeed, the browser used internally by Office Desktop for the add-ins is IE.

Comment: Thank you for the very thorough answer. I think I am out of luck installing the add-in with my account. Reading the docs more I think you are right that I cannot install add-ins because I am technically not using exchange: https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/publish/publish. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Also Vorlon.js looks amazing! Thanks for the link.