# How to share the created outlook plugin to someone without publishing it?

Tags: build, outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I'm new to outlook plugin development. I just created a sample plugin and I wanted it to share it with my friend But the files are in my local.

The reason behind I don't post my code here since its very basic and taken from the outlook doc itself. There is nothing more than that.

My question is, Is there any way to install it through js /manifest file on their mail? The sample plugin has some dependency files(script and images).

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

In short, you need to publish your web app to any web server which can be accessible to your friend and give him a manifest to sideload an add-in. See [Side loading an Outlook javascript add-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36672370/side-loading-an-outlook-javascript-add-in) for more information.

The [Sideload Outlook add-ins for testing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/sideload-outlook-add-ins-for-testing) article describes how to sideload add-in in Microsoft Office without putting the add-in into the catalog.

Comment: Hi @Eugene Astafiev, is there any possibility to share it without publishing it in the server since my friend is also in my network.The problem now is it runs in localhost , can you help to change it to local IP so that he can access it?

Comment: You can use a shared folder I believe.